# Why createStatement method is declared under Connection Interface instead of Statement interface?

Tags: java, mysql, interface

I'm going through one big doubt. Today I was practicing database connection and reading records from table in MySQL database. Everything worked fine.

While coding I came across two Interfaces, one Connection and second is Statement.
After setting up a connection using below code snippet .

```
Connection Con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
```

I had to create an Statement object which will be used for executing SQL query. So I did like this and was able to get records.

```
Statement stmnt = Con.createStatement();
String SQL = "SELECT * FROM sys_config";
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( SQL );
```

My Question is, If Statement object is required most of the time then why `createStatement()` is declared in `Connection` interface. Why it was not declared under Statement interface?  Is there is any specific reason which I'm really not aware of?

At the end, below code is being used to get an `Statement` reference to object which is implemented by `StatementImpl`.

```
public class ConnectionImpl
  extends ConnectionPropertiesImpl
  implements Connection
{...

public Statement createStatement()
    throws SQLException
  {
    return createStatement(1003, 1007);
  }

  public Statement createStatement(int resultSetType, int resultSetConcurrency)
    throws SQLException
  {
    checkClosed();

    StatementImpl stmt = new StatementImpl(this, this.database);
    stmt.setResultSetType(resultSetType);
    stmt.setResultSetConcurrency(resultSetConcurrency);

    return stmt;
  }


}
```

Comment: For the same reason that the `getConnection()` method is defined in `DriverManager`... You get a statement from a specific connection. That statement belongs to the connection, it doesn't come from thin air.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: If createStatement() was in Statement, you would need a Statement to create a Statement. How would you create the first one?

Comment: @JBNizet: but we do sometimes see static factory methods create instances of their own type, perhaps this is where the OP is confused (big guess on my part).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, Would you like to explain here please ?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 5):

The `createStatement()` method is not static. It relies on `Connection` data. If method was created as static in Statement interface, it would need to ask for Connection instance as input parameter.

Different `Connection` implementations might instantiate `Statements` in different ways (and with different implementations).

So it was decided to be part of the `Connection` responsibility to instantiate one.

Comment: Could you please explain more with small example, I'm not that much experienced in java ? :)

Comment: @LearnJava Let me rephrase your question, with a more concrete example. That should allow you to understand. "Why is the method `ToyotaCar createToyotaCar()` declared inside the class `ToyotaCarFactory` and not inside the class `ToyotaCar`?" The answer is that you need t toyota car factory with a chain assembly, a painting room, etc. to create toyota cars. A toyota car is not what allows creating a toyota car. Same for Connection/Statement. The connection is the object able to create statement. It contains the machinery that allows creating statements. You don't create a stmt from another stmt

Comment: @JBNizet...you really crushed that..!! Totally understood now..!! Thank you so much !!!..

Comment: @JBNizet, Today I was thinking one more scenario, I totally agree with your above answer but even lets say there is one ToyotaCarFactory  class which creates ToyotaCar and also there is one more class ToyotaCar. What kind of object ToyotaCar  class will create if it doesnt call createToyotaCar() method under ToyotaCarFactory   class ? Just a flesh, no bones nothing...? What's the benefit of having ToyotaCar class then ,  If actual product is coming out ToyotaCarFactory  class ? Just a blue print, that's it ?

Comment: ToyotaCar responsability is not to instantiate toyota cars, but instead to model toyota car properties and behaviour (in case you implement behaviour in the model layer). For example, you could have a Car interface with accelerate method. ToyotaCar will imolement accelerate in its own way; and HondaCar in (potentially) another way. ToyotaCarFactory would be responsible of providing ToyotaCar instances, but it's ToyotaCar responsibility to provide that actual car properties.